# MVC Basic - how to get html button in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new in MVC.

I have simple HTML website where I have two three inputs

1. input to write email adress
2. one checkbox
3. button

I have one HomeController which have on method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I want to generate method `[HttpPost]` after I click the button.

Now after I am click inputbutton in my Url I have just one change
Before click

```
http://localhost:52254/Home/Index
```

and after

```
http://localhost:52254/Home/Index?
```

There is a form

```
<form>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Wpisz adres email">
  </div>
  <br />
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </label>
  <br />
  <a href="/Controller/View">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign" class="btn btn-primary"/>
  </a>
 </form>
```

Comment: Seems like what you're asking for is extremely basic and covered in countless tutorials. Have you done any research to see how it's done?

Comment: Yes I did. I know its 100% basic but really I can't find it;(

Comment: follow Microsoft tutorials they are good to start http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: In your view, create a form. In your controller you should write your action method that your form will post to. Probably best to show your existing view in your question.

Comment: You shouldn't put your submit button in an `a` tag. Your form needs to have an action that points to the route to your `HttpPost` decorated action method. MVC has an HTML Helper that can assist you with this called [BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29).

Comment: You should really go over the tutorials tbo.rdz mentioned.  Everything you are doing is pretty much NOT the recommended way.  You are not using any MVC helpers and you are hardcoding urls.  I'd also mention that you need to do some research on *basic* html.  You should not put input elements in an href.  Anchor tags can never submit via post.

Answer (score 0):

Change The Code Like This

```html
   
@using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Wpisz adres email">
  </div>
  <br />
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </label>
  <br />
  <a>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign" class="btn btn-primary"/>
  </a>
}
```